# unexpected results for memory allocation with c malloc function

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, gdb, malloc

I have to allocate memory for 4 pointers to pointers on float (2D) over many iterations (6), but at the second iteration, malloc gives me the same address for two allocations. Code :

```
int i=0, a=0;
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    float** P_i=(float**) malloc(4*sizeof(float*));
    for(a=0;a<4;a++)    P_i[a]=(float*) calloc(4,sizeof(float));

    for(a=0;a<4;a++)    free(P_i[a]);
    free(P_i);
}
```

Debugging with gdb :

```
(gdb) print i
$42 = 1
(gdb) set $pos=0
(gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
$51 = (float *) 0x804d500
(gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
$52 = (float *) 0x804d148
(gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
$53 = (float *) 0x804d4e8
(gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
$54 = (float *) 0x804d500
```

P_i[0] and P_i[3] point to the same address 0x804d500 and I can't find why :/

Comment: C or C++? Use of `malloc` tends to suggest C, but casting the `void *` it returns is a C++ thing. If you're using C, _don't cast the return of `malloc` and co_

Comment: c. I've tried to remove the cast but I get an invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘float*’

Comment: What compiler are you using? If it's complaining about casting `malloc` return values, chances are you're using a C++ compiler

Comment: it's : gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Comment: I just checked it on Windows with VS 2012. I get four different addresses. It must be something specific to Ubuntu/gcc

Comment: Which line did you break on?

Comment: between the first for(a=0;a<4;a++) and the 2nd (before freeing)

Comment: @DahoM Can you just add a for loop between malloc and free loops to print the addresses, instead of using gdb?

Comment: @radoslav did it w/o gdb. now not duplicating on the 2nd iteration but the 4th... (headache!!)

Comment: You have a memory problem with calloc(). It  is allocating 16-bytes instead of 4 for each entry in your P_i array. I think that is jacking up your memory. Change it to calloc( 1, sizeof float ) and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: @TJohnson It's what I want, a 2D array of 6 ptrs, each pointing to 4 ptrs containing float types.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be calloc( 4, sizeof( float * ) )?

Comment: @TJohnson sorry, my bad, it's a square ptr to ptrs : 4 ptrs, each pointing to 4 ptrs... but for the calloc( 4, sizeof( float * )) I think it has to be sizeof( float) since the P_i[smthing1][smthing2] has to be a float ?

Comment: So why is a repeated address a problem?  Code does not _use_ the allocated data and so this repeat causes no issue.  AFAIK, the compiler is very smart and has optimized code.  1) _Use_ the allocated space like `P_i[a][0] = rand(); ... P_i[a][3] = rand(); /* gdb break */ print("%e %e %e %e\n", P_i[a][0] ...` 2) Use a _different_ values than `4` for the 2 dimensions  to help add clarity to the discussion.

Comment: Does this happen on the first iteration (`i == 0`) and first run of the code?

Comment: The above code is a shortened version to express my prblm. The repeated address causes me a lot of prblms since when 2 cells of my 2d structure share the same address, I can't change the value of one cell w/o altering the value of the other... I've tried P_i[0][0]=val1 and P_i[3][0]=val2, at the end P_i[0][0] is val2... HEEEELP!!!

Comment: If `i==0` works and others do not, then the effect of [@mgagnon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37275057/2410359) is a likely explanation.

Comment: "my 2d structure share the same address" this needs to be shown to occur in _code_, not the debugger.  Post the minimal _complete_ code that causes a problem.  Perhaps earlier _true_ code is corrupting memory and what you have here is just the after effects.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this bug ? I can't. Tried msvc and gcc and both gives the expected result, ie: no memory overlap.

Comment: as @chux proposed, currently checking for memory leaks, will forward results asap

Comment: Not enough information: Compilation flags? Where's the breakpoint, really? You can't put them on empty lines. Post a minimal example that reproduces the problem at runtime, without gdb. Unless your standard library is utterly broken, the code you gave cannot fail by itself.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem you were right from the beginning, the cast hides a memory corruption. I got rid of it and currently checking where the corruption shows up

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the cast was indeed hiding an ugly memory corruption caused by an ugly deallocation luckily finally fixed. Thank you for your help. thank all of you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

> between the first for(a=0;a<4;a++) and the 2nd (before freeing)

My guess is that gdb breaks on last iteration of the loop, before the last calloc() call. If it's the case P_i[3] have the address of the previous iteration.

Btw, it's hard to use gdb when there's more than one statement per line.

Comment: The break is set on the blank line between the 2 for loop, the execution stops right at the free for loop instruction (but doesn't even start the loop). I haven't mastered gdb yet, at all! but this far I am really impressed by its flexibility.

Comment: I suspect this is closest to reality.  Code does not _use_ `P_i[3]` and certain optimization may be in effect causing the break-point to not be in code where is appears to be in soruce.

Answer (score 1):

With information available this can't be answered, but let me try.

The code seems ok. I can't reproduce your problem either.

You can't really put a breakpoint on a blank line. I guess that would put it on a line with free.

My guess is, your code was compiled with optimization enabled, which probably reordered things making sure you are not really sure where execution has stopped. Disable optimization and re-build (on GCC that would be -O0). Or show us the disassembly (including current PC where you print).

My run on Ubuntu gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4 built with -O0 -g, stopped on a line with free (before it was executed):

> (gdb) print i
>   $1 = **0**
>   (gdb) set $pos=0
>   (gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
>   $2 = (float *) 0x602040
>   (gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
>   $3 = (float *) 0x602060
>   (gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
>   $4 = (float *) 0x602080
>   (gdb) print P_i[$pos++]
>   $5 = (float *) 0x6020a0
>   (gdb) bt
>   #0  main () at malloc.c:12
>   (gdb) list
>   7     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
>   8     {
>   9       float** P_i=(float**) malloc(4*sizeof(float*));
>   10      for(a=0;a<4;a++)    P_i[a]=(float*) calloc(4,sizeof(float));
>   11                   
>   12      for(a=0;a<4;a++)    free(P_i[a]);

Does your source code exhibit a problem even if you build it separately (not a part of larger program)? Do you have custom calloc / malloc implemented? What does "nm your-executable|grep calloc" show? It should be something like this:

> U calloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that I have a memory corruption appearing somewhere after the first iteration. I am digging and will forward asap.